# How to extract a string from a list of sets

Tags: python, list

I want to extract some information form a list of sets . I know that I  have to use python module `re` but i will be happy to have some help.
This is the list of sets:

```
[{'group_id': 'E1', 'subjects_affected': '4', 'subjects_at_risk': '104'},
 {'group_id': 'E2', 'subjects_affected': '7', 'subjects_at_risk': '105'}]
```

I want to extract information related to subjects_affected in each set. So I need to have :

```
['4','7']
```

Thank you,

Below is the current code:

```
import re

b=[{'group_id': 'E1', 'subjects_affected': '0', 'subjects_at_risk': '104'},
   {'group_id': 'E2', 'subjects_affected': '0', 'subjects_at_risk': '105'}]

re.findall(r'b\{\aff+\b', b)
```

Comment: Those aren't sets; they're dicts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension:

```py
>>> b=[{'group_id': 'E1', 'subjects_affected': '0', 'subjects_at_risk': '104'},
...  {'group_id': 'E2', 'subjects_affected': '0', 'subjects_at_risk': '105'}]
>>> [x['subjects_affected'] for x in b]
['0', '0']
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need re for this case:

```
c = [dic['subjects_affected'] for dic in b]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`map`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-map-function/) function to get all field values from the list of dicts:

```
b = [{'group_id': 'E1', 'subjects_affected': '4', 'subjects_at_risk': '104'},
     {'group_id': 'E2', 'subjects_affected': '7', 'subjects_at_risk': '105'}]
 
result = list(map(lambda elem: elem['subjects_affected'], b))

print(result)
```

Output:

```
['4', '7']
```